# What's the difference between EDGE Classic and Extended?

Tags: edge

I purchased the Android [Humble Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) and there are two different versions for EDGE that I can download/install, the "Classic" version (23.2 MB) and the "Extended" (23.1 MB).  What is the difference?

Comment: Ironic that the extended edition has a small file size...

Answer (score 7):

The levels are different. Classic has 48 classic difficulty levels and 16 hard levels. Extended has 48 extra levels. Seems like Extended is kind of like DLC to the first game. I haven't unlocked all of the levels for either yet, but I do have them both installed.

Comment: Are these the same levels though?

Comment: No, you'll have to play both games to get everything. On PC "Extended" is embedded into the base game (like a classic DLC), not so on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It's an expansion pack: they're entirely new levels and some new mechanics (such as the evil dark cube).

Comment: Hi TheGeorgeL, [we're all here to learn from each other.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette) While the answer may be obvious to you now, given [this was answered last February](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49603/3389), it's something you could've just left alone.

Comment: The answer existing wasn't very good

Answer (score 0):

the difference is the bonus levels and sounds. in classic, there are 17 bonus levels  (new bonus level ZIAS)and 19 unique tunes while extended has 15 bonus levels and 23 unique tunes.

Comment: *Why* are you sharing those links? And your numbers are different than the ones in the most upvoted answer: can you explain why your numbers are correct?